# Getting started with Web GIS development, especially vector editing?

Tags: open-source-gis, editing, web-gis

I would like to start developing a GIS web application for mapping and editing vector data with attributes. I'm familiar with Desktop GIS (ArcGIS, QGIS) and basic SQL. I've also little experience with GeoServer, XML and GML but I've no real programming experience (Java, etc.). I would like to do something similar like in this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUgulAqAqpA). It can be simple, for the start than shown in this video but there should be a possibility to create a feature (point, line, polygon) and enter various attribute data.

So my question is, how to start with the whole thing, what are the basics to read and which software (open source) is recommended?

Comment: Even if the duplicate leaves some unanswered questions, reviewing it should provide ideas for what to ask in a more focussed question about a specific aspect.

Comment: Good, this post matches in most cases with what I was looking for. I'll focus on Geoserver, PostGIS and check out OpenLayer. I suppose that there were several tutorials and beginners guides at the project websites. Thanks